# Node.js: Asynchronous nested callback not working within each iteration in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express

I have used following code snippets  to get  followers of a particular user which are stored in mongodb

Saved user json like below

```
{   "_id":{
    "$oid":"5440f606255cd4740e88ed21"   },   "username":"test2",   "email":"test2%40gmail.com",   "name":"Test2",   "version":null,   "password":"2ea01e7a318f15378641f47469613ce6817cc91a",   "gender":null,   "dob":null,   "profile_image":"1413543430090.jpg",   "status":"1",   "role_id":"2",   "posts":[
       ],   "followers":[
    {
      "_id":{
        "$oid":"5440fb8fad74e87c0fdf22e5"
      },
      "user_id":"5440f0c3ae7a24ac0e47ca9e",
      "unfollow":"0",
      "created":{
        "$date":"2014-10-17T11:20:47.107Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id":{
        "$oid":"5440fc1e51a684e00b72db8a"
      },
      "user_id":"5440f9790dd5d4a40b6cec18",
      "unfollow":0,
      "created":{
        "$date":"2014-10-17T11:23:10.645Z"
      }
    }   ] }
```

to get all followers of a user i have used following code snippet. In this code  followers get using foreach loop.

Main issue is that find query within foreach loop is not working because of a asynchronous callback function

```
  db.collection('users').findOne({'_id': new mongo.ObjectID('5440f606255cd4740e88ed21'), "followers.unfollow": '0'}, {followers: 1, _id: 1}, function(err, user) {

     var followers = user.followers;
     var finalarray = [];
        followers.forEach(function(follower, index) {


db.collection('users').find({"user._id": new mongo.ObjectID(follower._id)}, {_id: 1, username: 1, profile_picture: 1},function(err, users) {
                                if (user) {
                                    var temp_follower = [];
                                    temp_follower = {'follower_id': user._id, 'username': user.username,'profile_picture': user.profile_picture};
                                    finalarray.push(temp_follower);
                                }
                            });
                        });

    });

res.json({'replyCode': "success", 'replyMsg': "followers get successfully", 'followers': finalarray});
```

Finally in response JSON i have not find any follower user detail

Help me to get rid of this issue.

Thanks

Dinesh Prajapati

Comment: `find({"user._id":` seems like a typo to me. I think your second request just doesn't return anything because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $in operator instead of looping. Here is a sample code skeleton

```
    db.collection('users').findOne({'_id': new mongo.ObjectID('5440f606255cd4740e88ed21'), "followers.unfollow": '0'}, {followers: 1, _id: 1}, function(err, user) {

    db.collection('users').find({"user._id":{$in: user.followers }, {_id: 1, username: 1, profile_picture: 1},function(err, users) {
                res.json({'replyCode': "success", 'replyMsg': "followers get successfully", 'followers': users});
            }
    });
});
```

Note that to perform sql-join like operation you may have to use mapReduce kind of thing. You can refer this [link](http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/02/03/joins-now-possible-in-mongodb-2-4/).